# Phonegap: Open Safari from Webview

Tags: cordova

I installed InAppBrowser in latest Phonegap.

I run
        onInApp = window.open('http://URL.com/', 'WebView', 'location=no,closebuttoncaption=Done,toolbar=no');

It opens webview so I think.

Next from web-site loaded with that web-view - I need to open external URLs in Safari. So I tried open with _system. I tried window.opener to call function(but seems it's not supported).

I tried event listeners. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

It always appears that external URL opens inside webview also not in Safari.

Many thanks,
Oleg

p.s. It is also discussed here
https://forums.adobe.com/message/8999531

So there I wrote my replies to common answers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var inAppBrowser = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_system', 'location=yes');
```

See [docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#cordovainappbrowseropen).

Comment: Sorry you not read my post. I already in WebView. I already display site. I need to open Safari from Site. I don't need to open WebView per InAppBrowser as I already there.

Comment: And I have no access to cordova library and their plugins from WebView(my site).

Comment: You can't do that. Once the site in open in the InAppBrowser, subsequent links in the InAppBrowser will continue to open in the same InAppBrowser window.

Comment: You don't have access to any of the plugins or Cordova libs since your code isn't on the device. It being loaded remotely.

Comment: How Facebook work then? Do you think they loaded all pages as native phonegap app? I know they can be not cordova at all but anyway. I saw today vk.com from App and they open URL in App just in new window with URL but this way does not work when I was trying. I am sure there must be a way.

Comment: Please consider reading this before getting started (https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html). Should help answer most of your questions. Your core app code needs to be on the device, not loaded remotely through the InAppBrowser.

Comment: May be someone could reply on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39459207/phonegap-android-allow-specified-domains-not-restrict-other