# Phonegap android allow specified domains not restrict other

Tags: cordova

So this is a problem

> Phonegap android allow specified domains not restrict other

I set config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist.git" />
<allow-navigation href="http://domain.net/*" />
<access origin="http://domain.net" browserOnly="true" />
```

But webview still can open other domains.

It works well on iOS but not on Android.

Comment: You forgot to copy a part of your question here: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2207797

Comment: Sorry code was not displaying, now you see it.